# Centralize resources for solution

Tags: vb.net

Friends,
I am developing a project which include one exe type project and some dll type projects in a single solution. I am using some image type resources between these projects like application icon etc.
Now I must include these resources in each project.
My question is 
Is there any way so that I can create one dll project for resources and add all resources to that projects and access these resources in other project. 
Also is it possible to access these resources as properties [Like **My.Resources.appICON** or **newDL.Resources.appICON**] so that I don’t have to remember names of resources.

found some help - http://geekswithblogs.net/MarkPearl/archive/2011/03/02/centralizing-a-resource-file-among-multiple-projects-in-one-solution.aspx

but by this type i can use it only Programmatically not at design time like
select picture for picture box

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 not support shared resource files! but you can access to resource-file from 
code behind and set icons manually to your controls!

i read in MSDN forums next version of visual studio resolved this problem!

Comment: i am using visula studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

Just create a plain class library project which contains your resources, and reference it from other projects.

To instruct Visual Studio to make the generated resource classes **public**, change the access modifier in the resource editor to `public`, as described [here](http://www.dev102.com/2008/07/01/how-to-generate-public-classes-for-resource-files/). Alternatively, there is a tool for VS2005 called [ResX File Public Code Generator](http://altinoren.com/PermaLink,guid,5b69e6d6-86b0-4717-889a-94db78ff04b2.aspx).